# How do I make the label text of an element bold in javascript?

Tags: javascript

**My HTML :**

```
<div id="PDF">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pdf" name="pdf" value="pdf">
    <label for="pdf">PDF</label>
</div>
```

**My JS :**

```
document.addEventListener('change',function(event){
    if(event.target.id == "pdf"){
        if(event.target.checked == true){
            event.target.label.style.fontWeight = "bold";
        }
        else{
            event.target.label.style.fontWeight = "normal";
        }
    }
});
```

To my utter dismay, when I execute the code, I am greeted with this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'style')

How do I fix this issue?

Comment: There is no property 'label' on the target, which I guess should be the "checkbox"... You can log it out if it really is. Then you need to get its sibling (the label element) and change its style property.

Comment: do this instead : document.getElementById('pdf').addEventListener('change',function(event){
document.getElementById('pdflabel').style.fontWeight ="bold";
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues here. Firstly, the event target has no attribute of label. You should just select the label explicitly and change the styles. Secondly, I would recommend adding the event listener to only the `#pdf` div rather than the whole document. This way, you won't need to check for the ID and the event listener won't be fired on every change. For example:

```js
document.getElementById("pdf").addEventListener("click", event => {
  const label = document.querySelector("label[for=pdf]");
  if(event.target.checked == true){
    label.style.fontWeight = "bold";
  }
  else{
    label.style.fontWeight = "normal";
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this finds you well..

```js
let divid = document.getElementById('PDF');
let checkid = document.getElementById('pdf');
let labelid = document.getElementById('label');

 checkid.addEventListener( "change", () => {
       if(checkid.checked){
label.style.fontWeight='bold';
}
else{
label.style.fontWeight='normal';
}
      });
```

```html
<div id="PDF">
    <input type="checkbox" id="pdf" name="pdf" value="pdf">
    <label for="pdf" id="label"> PDF</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code actually target can have multiple labels.
So property is not `label` it is `labels`.

```
<div id="PDF">
  <input type="checkbox" id="pdf" name="pdf" value="pdf">
  <label for="pdf">PDF</label>
</div>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    if (event.target.id == "pdf") {
      if (event.target.checked == true) {
        event.target.labels[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
      } else {
        event.target.labels[0].style.fontWeight = "normal";
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```